# Tool to keep track of the Google rank of my website for a particular search

Tags: linux, web-apps, firefox, marketing, google-search

Let's say I own `stackexchange.com` and want to see how my website ranks or Google when people search "`recommended software`".

Example: Right now I see that the first `*.stackexchange.com/*` result is at the 36th place.

Requirements:

- Get the rank every day or week
- Show a graph or at least let me export the data
- Gratis
- Either running as an online service, OR on my Linux computer (*Native or Firefox plugin or Chromium plugin. My computer is not always connected to the Internet so in this case the software must try until a connection is available*).

Bonus:

- Ability to record several searches
- Ability to associate a particular language to a search (example: [Google Spain](https://www.google.es) for `software recomendado`)